# How to install BareOS on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, repository, add-apt-repository

Many repository directories are organized as dists, pool etc. And anyone can simply edit sources.list file in order to add new repo.

I need to add an extraordinarily structured repo like [this](http://download.bareos.org/bareos/release/latest/xUbuntu_16.04/).

How can I add this repo without supplying any release and repo name?

*(It seems that, according to given answer, adding  / at the end works, instead of release name repo name)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [official documentation](http://doc.bareos.org/master/html/bareos-manual-main-reference.html#x1-370002.3.3) we can use the following method:

> **2.3.3 Install on Debian based Linux Distributions**
>
> Debian / Ubuntu
>
> Bareos Version >= 15.2.0 requires the Jansson library package. On Ubuntu is it available in Ubuntu Universe. In Debian, is it included in the main repository.
>
> ```
> # 
> # define parameter 
> # 
>
> DIST=Debian_9.0 
> # or 
> # DIST=Debian_8.0 
> # DIST=xUbuntu_16.04 
> # DIST=xUbuntu_14.04 
> # DIST=xUbuntu_12.04 
>
> RELEASE=release/17.2/ 
> # or 
> # RELEASE=release/latest/ 
> # RELEASE=experimental/nightly/ 
>
> URL=http://download.bareos.org/bareos/$RELEASE/$DIST 
>
> # add the Bareos repository 
> printf "deb $URL /\n" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bareos.list 
>
> # add package key 
> wget -q $URL/Release.key -O- | apt-key add - 
>
> # install Bareos packages 
> apt-get update 
> apt-get install bareos bareos-database-postgresql
> ```

Mentioned Jansson [library is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=amd64&searchon=names&keywords=Jansson) on Ubuntu.